# Case-sensitive replacement

Tags: ruby, string

I have a string that may include the word `"favorite"` (in American English) or the capitalised `"Favorite"`. I want to substitute them with the British spelling `"favourite"` or `"Favourite"` respectively without changing the capitalisation.

I'm stuck with

```
element.gsub!(/Favorite/i, 'Favourite')
```

which will always capitalise the first letter. I don't want to make it too complicated or just repeat the substitution for the two cases. What is the best solution?

Comment: `gsub(/(f)avorite/i, '\1avourite')`?

Comment: thanks, that works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may capture the first letter and then use a `\1` backreference to insert the captured one back:

```
element.gsub!(/(f)avorite/i, '\1avourite')
               ^^^            ^^
```

See [this Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/YiJMPW).

The `(f)` capturing group, together with the `i` case insensitive modifier, will match `f` or `F`, and `\1` in the replacement pattern will paste this letter back.

Note that to replace whole words, you should use [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
element.gsub!(/\b(f)avorite\b/i, '\1avourite')
               ^^          ^^
```

Also, mind the single quotes used for the replacement string literal, if you use double quotation marks, you will need to double the backslash.

Comment: What if the word is "esthetics" in the American spelling and "aesthetics" in the English spelling?

Comment: @sawa How can `/\b(f)avorite\b/i` match `aavorite`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You were right. I somehow mistook your `()` for `()?`.

Answer (score 2):

```
subs = {
  'center'   =>'centre',    'defense'   =>'defense',
  'behavour' =>'behaviour', 'apologize' =>'apologise',
  'maneuver' =>'manoeuvre', 'pediatric' =>'paediatric',
  'traveled' =>'travelled', 'honor'     =>'honour',
  'favorite' =>'favourite', 'esthetics'  =>'aesthetics'
}

str = "My Favorite uncle, Max, an honorable gent, is \
       often the Center of attention at parties, mainly \
       because he has a great sense for Esthetics. \
       I apologize for my clumsy maneuver.".squeeze(' ') 

str.gsub(/\b\p{Alpha}+\b/) do |word|
  key = word.downcase
  if subs.key?(key)
    new_word = subs[key]
    new_word.capitalize! if word.match?(/\A\p{Upper}/)
    word = new_word
  end
  word
end
  #=> "My Favourite uncle, Max, an honorable gent, is \ 
  #    often the Centre of attention at parties, mainly \
  #    because he has a great sense for Aesthetics. \
  #    I apologise for my clumsy manoeuvre."
```

`"honorable"` is not modified because it is not a key in the hash `subs` (even though it contains the key `"honor"`). A fuller example might include that word as a key.